# How to get name and email of every person in address book contacts

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.now I am struck in my project in the task of getting all the names and email address of every person which are placed in address book contacts in to an array.if any body know this one can you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558543/iphone-address-book-sample-code the official doc is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/ https://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/index.html

Comment: Unless tou are actively adding value to the user, scanning their address book is somewhat of shady activity and should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

```
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
[menuArray removeAllObjects];
if(menuArray ==nil)
    menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *localDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

//    ABRecordID recordId = ABRecordGetRecordID(ref);
//    [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",recordId] forKey:@"Record_Id"];


    //get firstname
    CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName] forKey:@"first_name"];

    //get lastname
    CFStringRef lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName] forKey:@"last_name"];

//    NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
//    [localDic setObject:contactFirstLast forKey:@"FullName"];





    //get EmailId
    ABMutableMultiValueRef EmailIds = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    CFTypeRef EmailId;
    NSString *EmailLabel;


    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(EmailIds); i++) {
        EmailLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(EmailIds,i)];

        if([EmailLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
        {
            EmailId = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(EmailIds,i);
            [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",EmailId] forKey:@"Email_Home"];

        }
        else if([EmailLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
        {
            EmailId = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(EmailIds,i);
            [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",EmailId] forKey:@"Email_Work"];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

here is code for name, email and phone number

```
    -(NSMutableArray*)getEmailAndPhoneOfPhoneContacts
    {

        NSLog(@"getPhoneContacts");

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool= [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook=ABAddressBookCreate();
        if(!iPhoneAddressBook)
        {
            DLog(@"unable to open addressBook");
        }


        CFArrayRef allPeople=ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(iPhoneAddressBook);
        NSMutableArray *peopleArray=[NSMutableArray  arrayWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)allPeople];

        BOOL shouldReleasePool=NO;

        NSInteger i;
        NSLog(@"Num of people while getting from address bool %d and syncing",[peopleArray count]);
        for(i=0;i<[peopleArray count];i++)
        {



            ABRecordRef record=[peopleArray objectAtIndex:i];

            Contact *objPhoneContact=[[Contact alloc] init];
            objPhoneContact.contactType=STATIC_CONTACT;




        CFStringRef prefixName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPrefixProperty);
        CFStringRef firstName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        CFStringRef middleName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonMiddleNamePhoneticProperty);
        CFStringRef lastName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        CFStringRef suffixName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonSuffixProperty);
        NSMutableString *contactname =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];



        // concating all the names
        if (prefixName) {
            [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)prefixName]];
            CFRelease(prefixName);
        }
        if (firstName) {
            [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)firstName]];
            CFRelease(firstName);
        }
        if (middleName) {
            [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)middleName]];
            CFRelease(middleName);
        }
        if (lastName) {
            [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)lastName]];
            CFRelease(lastName);
        }
        if (suffixName) {
            [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)suffixName]];
            CFRelease(suffixName);
        }
        // if emty then get the organization property
        if (contactname == nil || [contactname length]<1) {
            CFStringRef orgName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
            if (orgName) {
                [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)orgName]];
                CFRelease(orgName);
            }

        }
        //if still empty then assign (no name) to it
        if (contactname == nil || [contactname length]<1)
            [contactname setString:@"(no name)"];

            objPhoneContact.mContactName = [contactname stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

            [contactname release];
            contactname = nil;
            ABMutableMultiValueRef multi;
            int multiCount=0;



            multi = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

            NSUInteger phoneIndex_mobile=11;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_iPhone=31;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_home=51;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_work=71;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_main=91;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_home_fax=111;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_work_fax=131;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_pager=151;
            NSUInteger phoneIndex_other=171;  

            multiCount=ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
            if(multiCount ==0)
            {
                //objPhoneContact.mPhoneNum=@"";
            }
            else 
            {
                for( int i=0; i < multiCount; i++)
                {

                    ContactProperty* objPhoneContactProperty=[[ContactProperty alloc] init];

                    objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropertyString=(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
                    objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName=(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
                    objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName=[objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_$!<>"]];

                    //          DLog(@"Display name %@",objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName);



                    if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"mobile"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_mobile;
                        phoneIndex_mobile++;
                    }
                    else if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"iPhone"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_iPhone;
                        phoneIndex_iPhone++;
                    }
                    else if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"home"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_home;
                        phoneIndex_home++;
                    }
                    else if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"work"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_work;
                        phoneIndex_work++;
                    }
                    else if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"main"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_main;
                        phoneIndex_main++;
                    }
                    else if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"HomeFAX"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_home_fax;
                        phoneIndex_home_fax++;
                    }
                    else if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"WorkFAX"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_work_fax;
                        phoneIndex_work_fax++;
                    }
                    else if([objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"pager"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_pager;
                        phoneIndex_pager++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSRange range1,range2,range3;

                        range1=[objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName rangeOfString:@"mobile" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                        range2=[objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName rangeOfString:@"home" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                        range3=[objPhoneContactProperty.mDisplayName rangeOfString:@"work" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                        if (range1.location!=NSNotFound) 
                        {
                            objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_mobile;
                            phoneIndex_mobile++;
                        }
                        else if (range2.location!=NSNotFound) 
                        {
                            objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_home;
                            phoneIndex_home++;
                        }
                        else if (range3.location!=NSNotFound) 
                        {
                            objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_work;
                            phoneIndex_work++;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            objPhoneContactProperty.mContactPropId=phoneIndex_other;
                            phoneIndex_other++;
                        }
                    }

                    objPhoneContactProperty.mContactDataType=@"Phone";

                    [objPhoneContact.mPropertyArray addObject:objPhoneContactProperty];
                    [objPhoneContactProperty release];
                }
            }

            if(multi)
                CFRelease(multi);



            multi=ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonEmailProperty);

            NSUInteger emailIndex_home=301;
            NSUInteger emailIndex_work=321;
            NSUInteger emailIndex_other=341;  //~400

            multiCount=ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
            if(multiCount ==0)
            {
                //objPhoneContact.mEmailId=@"";
            }
            else 
            {
                for( int i=0; i < multiCount; i++)
                {
                    ContactProperty* objEmailContactProperty=[[ContactProperty alloc] init];

                    objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropertyString=(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
                    objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName=(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
                    objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName=[objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_$!<>"]];


                    if([objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"home"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=emailIndex_home;
                        emailIndex_home++;
                    }
                    else if([objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"work"]==NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=emailIndex_work;
                        emailIndex_work++;
                    }
                    /*
                     else if([objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"other"]==NSOrderedSame)
                     {
                     objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",emailIndex_other];
                     emailIndex_other++;
                     }
                     */
                    else 
                    {
                        objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=emailIndex_other;
                        emailIndex_other++;
                    }

                    objEmailContactProperty.mContactDataType=@"Email";

                    [objPhoneContact.mPropertyArray addObject:objEmailContactProperty];
                    [objEmailContactProperty release];
                }
            }

            if(multi)
                CFRelease(multi);

            [tempArray addObject:objPhoneContact];
            [objPhoneContact release];

            if(shouldReleasePool)
            {
                [innerPool drain];
                shouldReleasePool=NO;
            }

        }
        self.mPhoneContactArray=tempArray;
        CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);
        CFRelease(allPeople);


        [pool drain];
        return [tempArray autorelease];
    }
```